# pytest fixture not found when used in parametrize

Tags: pytest, fixtures, parametrized-testing, pytest-fixtures

```
@pytest.fixture
def text():
    return "My fixture text for testing.\n"

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    ("some_boolean_param", "text"),
    [
        (True, text), 
        (False, text),
    ],
)
def test_my_function(some_boolean_param, text, request):
    fixture_text = request.getfixturevalue(text)
    # do something with fixture_text and some_boolean param...
```

Results in:

```
E       fixture '<function text at 0x160acb280>' not found
>       available fixtures: fixture1, ..., text, another_fixture, ...
```

However if I put the fixture value inside a string, it just returns the string:

```
@pytest.fixture
def text():
    return "My fixture text for testing.\n"

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    ("some_boolean_param", "text"),
    [
        (True, "text"), 
        (False, "text"),
    ],
)
def test_my_function(some_boolean_param, text, request):
    fixture_text = request.getfixturevalue(text)
```

Results in:

```
>>> text
>>> "text"
>>> fixture_text
>>> "text"
```

How can I pass in the fixture to parametrize and get parametrize to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code overrides the fixture name, please work with the following code:

```
import pytest
@pytest.fixture
def text():
    return "My fixture text for testing.\n"

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    ("some_boolean_param", "fixture_name"), # dont override fixture name
    [
        (True, "text"), 
        (False, "text"),
    ],
)
def test_my_function(some_boolean_param, fixture_name, request):
    fixture_text = request.getfixturevalue(fixture_name)
    print(f"text from fixture:{fixture_text}")
```